# ADF Copy activity to handle csv files with json fields

Tags: csv, azure-data-factory

I have a couple of csv files located in an Azure blob, the csv files contains json strings in some of the fields.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4koMj.png)
I want to ingest these csv files to an azure s using a copy activity but the copy activity schema parser is separating the json fields since the json string contains a comma ";"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icL2Q.png)

Is there a work-around to handle this?

I also tried using a mapping data flow but still got the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your input data, the tier column has column delimiter  and Quote character as a value itself in that column. Thus, you need to specify the Quote character as double quotes (`"`) to ignore the commas within the quote characters and Escape character as double quotes(`"`), to ignore the double quotes within the string.

**Json code of dataset settings typeProperties:**

```
"typeProperties": {
    "location": {
    },
    "columnDelimiter": ",",
    "escapeChar": "\"",
    "firstRowAsHeader": true,
    "quoteChar": "\""
}
```

[image]